# Break tag from SQL server to C# UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I having logic in SQL Server stored procedure where i am using next line char,

```
CASE   
   WHEN DATEPART(hh, InseptionDate) > 12  
    THEN CAST(YEAR(InseptionDate) AS VARCHAR) + N'年' + CAST(MONTH(InseptionDate) AS VARCHAR) + N'月' +   
      CAST(DAY(InseptionDate) AS VARCHAR) + N'日' + N'午後' + CAST(DATEPART(hh, InseptionDate) - 12 AS VARCHAR) + N'時' + N'から' 
      +CHAR(13)+ 
      CAST(YEAR(ExpiryDate) AS VARCHAR) + N'年' + CAST(MONTH(ExpiryDate) AS VARCHAR) + N'月' +   
      CAST(DAY(ExpiryDate) AS VARCHAR) + N'日' + N'午後4時まで' + CAST(PolicyTerm AS VARCHAR) + N'年間'  
   ELSE CAST(YEAR(InseptionDate) AS VARCHAR) + N'年' + CAST(MONTH(InseptionDate) AS VARCHAR) + N'月' +   
     CAST(DAY(InseptionDate) AS VARCHAR) + N'日' + N'午前' + CAST(DATEPART(hh, InseptionDate) AS VARCHAR) + N'時' + N'から' +   
     +'<br/>' +   
     CAST(YEAR(ExpiryDate) AS VARCHAR) + N'年' + CAST(MONTH(ExpiryDate) AS VARCHAR) + N'月' +   
     CAST(DAY(ExpiryDate) AS VARCHAR) + N'日' + N'午後4時まで' + CAST(PolicyTerm AS VARCHAR) + N'年間'  
   END AS PolicyPeriod,
```

The returned policyperiod value is assigned to property like below, 
    PolicyPeriod = Helpers.Get(obj, "PolicyPeriod"),

In view page this policyperiod is assinged to like below,when i mouse over the policy period in visual studio in running mode, it shows the value as below with break tag,

```
2014年7月31日午前0時から<br/>2016年7月31日午後4時まで2年間
```

why this break tag is not recognized by browser... Should i have to change anything in @Html.Label property

```
@Html.Label(Model.PolicyPeriod, new { id = "", name = "" })
```

Below is the extension method for the label

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "ReviewUnusedParameters", MessageId = "helper", Justification = "Required for Extension Method")]
        public static MvcHtmlString Label(this HtmlHelper helper, string value, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            TagBuilder labelBuilder = new TagBuilder("label");
            Dictionary<string, object> attributes = htmlAttributes as Dictionary<string, object>;
            if (attributes != null)
            {
                labelBuilder.MergeAttributes(attributes);
            }
            labelBuilder.SetInnerText(value);
            return new MvcHtmlString(labelBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
        }
```

Here the CHAR(13) or break tag which i have appended in sql is not working.

```
Actual result: 2014年7月31日午前0時から<br/>2016年7月31日午後4時まで2年間

Expected result:2014年7月31日午前0時から
                  2016年7月31日午後4時まで2年間
```

Both char(13) and `<br/>` tag not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`TagBuilder.SetInnerText(string)` sets the InnerHtml property of the element to an **HTML-encoded** version of the specified string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder.setinnertext%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

Use `@Html.Raw()`.

Comment: yeah it is working..Thanks, but is there any other way we can do this with html encoded